# Frigga's Protection and Odin's Chosen in game of Blood Rage

Tags: blood-rage

**Frigga's Protection - clan upgrade**

> You may pay 1 rage to prevent a figure of yours from being destroyed.

**Odin's Chosen - Mystic ability**

> Your mystics may invade a village occupied by a warrior or mystic, destroying that figure.

What happens when Mystic owner invades destroying the warrior, but warrior's owner uses Frigga's Protection to save the warrior?

In your answer please consider that there might not be an unoccupied village in the warrrior's province.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[If the other player spends 1 Rage to keep his figure in place, the active player is unable to perform his invasion and basically loses his turn.](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1585493/failed-odins-chosen)

From Thiago Arnha, Producer, rules writer, and play tester of Blod rage. He designed Arcada Quest with Eric Lang.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with Becq Starforged, who commented that this can be used by the mystic's owner to stall and/or drain Rage from the warrior's owner.